# How to use PalletInstance in XCM?

Tags: polkadot, xcm

I'm going through the xcm and stumbled on junciton `PalletInstance`, and was wondering how to use it.
I have 2 questions here:

1. Will I be able to call extrinsics of other chain via XCM?
2. Will I be able to modify the storage of a pallet on other chain?

If someone could clarify the same ,it would be very helpful, and point to the relevant resources to read about it.

Answer (score 1):

> Will I be able to call extrinsics of other chain via XCM?

Yes, You can do it through the `Transact` instruction.

> Will I be able to modify the storage of a pallet on other chain?

Sure, for example, there is an extrinsic in ChainA can change the storage of its pallet, you can call it via XCM from ChainB, then the storage in ChainA will be changed.

These two questions are unrelated to `PalletInstance`, which is an instanced, indexed pallet that forms a constituent part of the context. Each pallet used in [`construct_runtime!`](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/v6.3.4/runtime/darwinia/src/lib.rs#L115) is a instanced pallet (PalletInstance). And in XCM, it's also a Junction. For example, [Darwinia use the PalletInstance(Balance Pallet index)](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/v6.3.4/runtime/darwinia/src/pallets/polkadot_xcm.rs#L107) to represent the native token ID.